# Capture multivalues with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that always captures `myValue` (this name is figurative, it can change, it's just to know the position of the value), but in some cases where unexpected characters enter like `-`, my regex fails, any suggestions?

regex:

```
.+-|(.*)(:)
```

sample:

```
abc:abe-myValue-ora:RZ
abe-myValue:mySAP
web543-p:abd-myValue-p:RZ
VM:afd-myValue.sl:ESX
VM:EUA-myValue:ESX
myValue:98
abc-myValue:98
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xDHb1J/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not specified all the rules of this match, here is a possible solution based on your examples:

```sh
^(?:.*?-)?([^:.-]{2,})[:.-]
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDHb1J/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:.*?-)?`: Match 0 or more of any character followed by `-` in an *optional* match
- `([^:.-]{2,})`: Match 2 or more of any character that are not included
- `[:.-]`: Match `:` or `.` or `-`

Comment: I tested the regex, but I discovered some new issues, sorry for the inconvenience, do you think it is possible to adjust the current regex? I added them on the link regex101

Comment: Just for your science, these are the names of monitoring agents, where I’m trying to capture the hostname of the server inside them

Comment: In the new samples do you always want to capture `value`?

Comment: Yes, myValue, my-Value and my-Value-with-number45

Comment: I realized that there are some samples outside the standard, probably human flaws in the configuration

Comment: If this is not feasible in the regex, I can consider it as an error rate for these cases

Comment: You can try: `^(?:.*?[:-])?([^\n:.-]{3,})[:.-]` but please understand regex can work with given rules. We need to have clear rules how these records are structured.

Comment: yes, there are some anomalies in these samples, but thank you very much for helping me !!